# Running Multiplication in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

### GTS Table

```
CCP months   QUART   YEARS  GTS
----  ------  -----    ----- ---
CCP1    1       1   2015    5
CCP1    2       1   2015    6
CCP1    3       1   2015    7
CCP1    4       2   2015    4
CCP1    5       2   2015    2
CCP1    6       2   2015    2
CCP1    7       3   2015    3
CCP1    8       3   2015    2
CCP1    9       3   2015    1
CCP1    10      4   2015    2
CCP1    11      4   2015    3
CCP1    12      4   2015    4
CCP1     1      1   2016    8
CCP1     2      1   2016    1
CCP1     3      1   2016    3
```

### Baseline table

```
CCP BASELINE   YEARS    QUART
----  --------   -----  -----
CCP1    5       2015    1
```

**Expected result**

```
CCP months  QUART    YEARS  GTS   result
----  ------  -----    ----- ---   ------

CCP1    1       1   2015    5     25   -- 5 * 5 (here 5 is the baseline)
CCP1    2       1   2015    6     30   -- 6 * 5 (here 5 is the baseline)
CCP1    3       1   2015    7     35   -- 7 * 5 (here 5 is the baseline)
CCP1    4       2   2015    4     360  -- 90 * 4(25+30+35 = 90 is the basline)
CCP1    5       2   2015    2     180  -- 90 * 2(25+30+35 = 90 is the basline)
CCP1    6       2   2015    2     180  -- 90 * 2(25+30+35 = 90 is the basline)
CCP1    7       3   2015    3     2160.00  -- 720.00 * 3(360+180+180 = 720)
CCP1    8       3   2015    2     1440.00  --   720.00 * 2(360+180+180 = 720)
CCP1    9       3   2015    1     720.00   --   720.00 * 1(360+180+180 = 720)
CCP1    10      4   2015    2     8640.00  --   4320.00
CCP1    11      4   2015    3     12960.00 --   4320.00
CCP1    12      4   2015    4     17280.00 --   4320.00
CCP1     1      1   2016    8     311040.00 --  38880.00
CCP1     2      1   2016    1     77760.00  --  38880.00
CCP1     3      1   2016    3     116640.00 --  38880.00
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d78d2)

**Explantion**

Baseline table has single baseline value for each CCP.

The baseline value should be applied to first quarter of each CCP and for the next quarters previous quarter sum value will be the basleine.

Here is a working query in `Sql Server 2008`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  b.CCP,
            Baseline = CAST(b.Baseline AS DECIMAL(15,2)),
            b.Years,
            b.Quart,
            g.Months,
            g.GTS,
            Result = CAST(b.Baseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15,2)),
            NextBaseline = SUM(CAST(b.Baseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2))) OVER(PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart),
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart ORDER BY g.Months)
    FROM    #GTS AS g
            INNER JOIN #Base AS b
                ON B.CCP = g.CCP
               AND b.QUART = g.QUART
               AND b.YEARS = g.YEARS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  b.CCP,
            CAST(b.NextBaseline AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
            b.Years,
            b.Quart + 1,
            g.Months,
            g.GTS,
            Result = CAST(b.NextBaseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15,2)),
            NextBaseline = SUM(CAST(b.NextBaseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2))) OVER(PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart),
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart ORDER BY g.Months)
    FROM    #GTS AS g
            INNER JOIN CTE AS b
                ON B.CCP = g.CCP
               AND b.Quart + 1 = g.QUART
               AND b.YEARS = g.YEARS
               AND b.RowNumber = 1
)
SELECT  CCP, Months, Quart, Years, GTS, Result, Baseline
FROM    CTE;
```

**UPDATE :**

To work with more than one year

```
;WITH order_cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_rank() OVER(partition BY ccp ORDER BY years, quart) d_rn,*
         FROM   #gts),
     CTE
     AS (SELECT b.CCP,
                Baseline = Cast(b.Baseline AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
                g.Years,
                g.Quart,
                g.Months,
                g.GTS,
                d_rn,
                Result = Cast(b.Baseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
                NextBaseline = Sum(Cast(b.Baseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2)))
                                 OVER(
                                   PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart),
                RowNumber = Row_number()
                              OVER(
                                PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart
                                ORDER BY g.Months)
         FROM   order_cte AS g
                INNER JOIN #Baseline AS b
                        ON B.CCP = g.CCP
                           AND b.QUART = g.QUART
                           AND b.YEARS = g.YEARS
         UNION ALL
         SELECT b.CCP,
                Cast(b.NextBaseline AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
                g.Years,
                g.Quart,
                g.Months,
                g.GTS,
                g.d_rn,
                Result = Cast(b.NextBaseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
                NextBaseline = Sum(Cast(b.NextBaseline * g.GTS AS DECIMAL(15, 2)))
                                 OVER(
                                   PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart),
                RowNumber = Row_number()
                              OVER(
                                PARTITION BY g.CCP, g.years, g.quart
                                ORDER BY g.Months)
         FROM   order_cte AS g
                INNER JOIN CTE AS b
                        ON B.CCP = g.CCP
                           AND b.d_rn + 1 = g.d_rn
                           AND b.RowNumber = 1)
SELECT CCP,
       Months,
       Quart,
       Years,
       GTS,
       Result,
       Baseline
FROM   CTE;
```

Now am looking for a solution in `Sql Server 2012+` which will utilize `SUM OVER(ORDER BY)` functionality or any better way

Tried something like this

```
EXP(SUM(LOG(Baseline * GTS)) OVER (PARTITION BY CCP ORDER BY Years,Quart ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
```

But didnt workout

Comment: What change between 2008 and 2012 and broke your query?

Comment: I believe you still need a recursive CTE to do this in 2012.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - If possible can you put one as answer

Comment: You're trying to do GTS * N where N = Baseline or SUM(Previous Quarter GTS)?

Comment: Your fiddle have an difference, Say baseline is 10 but here your sample say 5

Comment: I guess baseline reset at begin of the year? So is only 4 depth recursion for each year?

Comment: Why didnt workout?? `The function 'Exp' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.` ??

Comment: It is a kind of work with cursor or recursive cte, but I would do this in some programming language.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - Sadly Programming language is not a option for me

Comment: @Sick Could you provide full result for your example

Comment: @lad2025 just give me 10mins will add it

Comment: @lad2025 - updated check now

Comment: @Sick Ok, now is clearer, I will play with it for a while :)

Comment: @lad2025 great :)  if possible try ti utilize sql server 2012 sum over( order by)  concept..  i have a feeling it can be used

Comment: @lad2025 dude any update

Comment: @Sick, what happens when `CCP1` goes into 2016? Can it happen at all? Should running calculation just continue into 2016? Should there be another row in `Baseline` with `Q=1 and Y=2016` in this case? It would help if you extended sample data and expected results into 2016 to show us how it should work. Is it possible to have partial years? Say, can `gts` table have 16 rows for `CCP1` starting from Jan 2015 till Apr 2016?

Comment: Does this need to be solved as a single select - say in a view?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - There will be only one baseline per CCP. So 2016 baseline will come from previous quarter sum (ie) `Q4 2015`. Yes partial rows are possible.

Comment: @sstan - I hoping to get an answer using `SUM() OVER(ORDER BY..)` functionality present in `Sql Server 2012` which should be better than my query. Or any better way

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - updated sample data and expected result

Comment: @Sick you didnt answer my question or comment in my answer. What is the problem with recursive CTE? What is the problem with 2008 version?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I am looking for solution which avoids recursion or Loops. Nothing wrong with CTE it is working fine

Comment: @Sick Unfortunately I've haven't find `pretty` solution yet.

Comment: @lad2025 - Ok that's fine. Take your time Bounty will end only after 7 days :)

Comment: @Sick - In your solution would you be able/willing to work with Date datatype rather than Years and months as Int?

Comment: @BradD - yes we can convert `Years` and `months` to `date` if needed   that's not a problem

Comment: @MM93 Really, deleting [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775650/multpilcation-aggregate-in-sql-server/33776736#33776736) without comment? I regret I lose my time producing demo

Comment: @lad2025 -My apologies, Big Sorry!! even i was thinking like i wasted your time. but i felt question is kind of stupid so deleted.

Comment: @MM93 Never mind, just don't do it in future.

Comment: @Prdp I added an answer after seeing your comment in Aaron Bertrand's blog post about running totals ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following solution assumes there are always 3 rows per quarter (only the last quarter might be partial), single SELECT, no recursion :-)

```
WITH sumQuart AS
 (
   SELECT *,
      CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() -- for the 1st month in a quarter
             OVER (PARTITION BY CCP, Years, Quart
                   ORDER BY months) = 1
                  -- return the sum of all GTS of this quarter
        THEN SUM(GTS) OVER (PARTITION BY CCP, Years, Quart)
        ELSE NULL -- other months
      END AS sumGTS
   FROM gts
 )
,cte AS
 (
   SELECT 
      sq.*,
      COALESCE(b.Baseline, -- 1st quarter
               -- product of all previous quarters
               CASE
                 WHEN MIN(ABS(sumGTS)) -- any zeros?
                      OVER (PARTITION BY sq.CCP ORDER BY sq.Years, sq.Quart, sq.Months 
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING) = 0 
                   THEN 0  
                 ELSE -- product
                      EXP(SUM(LOG(NULLIF(ABS(COALESCE(b.Baseline,1) * sumGTS),0)))
                          OVER (PARTITION BY sq.CCP ORDER BY sq.Years, sq.Quart, sq.Months 
                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING)) -- product
                      -- odd number of negative values -> negative result
                    * CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN sumGTS < 0 THEN 1 END) 
                                OVER (PARTITION BY sq.CCP ORDER BY sq.Years, sq.Quart, sq.Months 
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING) % 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
               END) AS newBaseline
   FROM sumQuart AS sq
   LEFT JOIN BASELINE AS b
          ON B.CCP = sq.CCP
          AND b.Quart = sq.Quart
          AND b.Years = sq.Years
 )
SELECT 
   CCP, months, Quart, Years, GTS,
   round(newBaseline * GTS,2),
   round(newBaseline,2)
FROM cte
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c120d/1)

EDIT:
Added logic to handle values <= 0 [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ddf23/2)

Comment: Looks promising and kind of answer am looking for :). Will test it tomorrow will real time data. Also what do meant by  *(only the last quarter might be partial*

Comment: @Sick: e.g. only July and August, but no September, for the last quarter

Comment: From start to end all the quarters will have 3 months :)

Comment: Wow. I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: This query is insanely faster than my original query. :)

Comment: @dnoeth - Query fails when `LOG()` get anything less than 1

Comment: @sick: What do you mean by "*fails*", error or wrong result? `EXP/LOG` only works for positive values, so I would assume that it fails for a `n <= 0`, but not for `0 < n< 1`. Can you add a new `CCP`  showing this?

Comment: @sick: Adding `ABS` and `NULLIF` deals with zero and negative values, but what is the expected result for negative values? Does your updated recursive CTE return correct data? See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13e95/6

Comment: @dnoeth - yes recursive CTE returns correct result. Even with negative values multiplication should happen.

Comment: @sick: Added logic to return the correct result for `n <= 0`, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ddf23/2

Comment: @dnoeth - Brilliant!!

Answer (score 4):

Another method that uses the `EXP(SUM(LOG()))` trick and only window functions for the running total (no recursive CTEs or cursors).

Tested at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e0d042ae452d9c0121d7ca570807d9c6)**:

```
WITH 
  ct AS
  ( SELECT  
        ccp, years, quart, 
        q2 = round(exp(coalesce(sum(log(sum(gts))) 
                                OVER (PARTITION BY ccp 
                                      ORDER BY years, quart 
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                               AND 1 PRECEDING)
                               , 0))
                  , 2)     -- round appropriately to your requirements
    FROM gts 
    GROUP BY ccp, years, quart
  )
SELECT  
    g.*, 
    result = g.gts * b.baseline * ct.q2,
    baseline = b.baseline * ct.q2
FROM ct 
  JOIN gts AS g
    ON  ct.ccp   = g.ccp
    AND ct.years = g.years 
    AND ct.quart = g.quart 
  CROSS APPLY
        ( SELECT TOP (1) b.baseline
          FROM baseline AS b
          WHERE b.ccp = ct.ccp
          ORDER BY b.years, b.quart
        ) AS b
  ;
```

**How it works:**

- (`CREATE` tables and `INSERT` skipped)
- **1**, lets group by ccp, year and quart and calculate the sums:

> ```
>     select 
>         ccp, years, quart,
>         q1 = sum(gts)
>     from gts 
>     group by ccp, years, quart ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ccp  | years | quart | q1       
> :--- | ----: | ----: | :--------
> CCP1 |  2015 |     1 | 18.000000
> CCP1 |  2015 |     2 | 8.000000 
> CCP1 |  2015 |     3 | 6.000000 
> CCP1 |  2015 |     4 | 9.000000 
> CCP1 |  2016 |     1 | 12.000000
> ```

- **2**, we use the `EXP(LOG(SUM())` trick to calculate the running multiplications of these sums. We use `BETWEEEN .. AND -1 PRECEDING` in the window to skip the current values, as these values are only used for the baselines of the next quart.
  The rounding is to avoid inaccuracies that come from using `LOG()` and `EXP()`. You can experiment with using either `ROUND()` or casting to `NUMERIC`:

> ```
> with 
>   ct as
>   ( select 
>         ccp, years, quart,
>         q1 = sum(gts)
>     from gts 
>     group by ccp, years, quart
>   )
> select 
>     ccp,  years, quart, -- months, gts, q1,
>     q2 = round(exp(coalesce(sum(log(q1)) 
>                             OVER (PARTITION BY ccp 
>                                   ORDER BY Years, Quart 
>                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
>                                            AND 1 PRECEDING),0)),2)
> from ct ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ccp  | years | quart |   q2
> :--- | ----: | ----: | ---:
> CCP1 |  2015 |     1 |    1
> CCP1 |  2015 |     2 |   18
> CCP1 |  2015 |     3 |  144
> CCP1 |  2015 |     4 |  864
> CCP1 |  2016 |     1 | 7776
> ```

- **3**, we combine the two queries in one (no need for that, it just makes the query more compact, you could have 2 CTEs instead) and then join to `gts` so we can multiply each value with the calculated `q2` (which gives us the baseline).
  The `CROSS APPLY` is merely to get the base baseline for each ccp.
  Note that I change this one slightly, to `numeric(22,6)` instead of rounding to 2 decimal places. The results are the same with the sample but they may differ if the numbers are bigger or not integer:

> ```
> with 
>   ct as
>   ( select 
>         ccp, years, quart, 
>         q2 = cast(exp(coalesce(sum(log(sum(gts)))
>                                 OVER (PARTITION BY ccp 
>                                       ORDER BY years, quart 
>                                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
>                                                AND 1 PRECEDING)
>                                , 0.0))
>                    as numeric(22,6))           -- round appropriately to your requirements
>     from gts 
>     group by ccp, years, quart
>   )
> select 
>     g.*, 
>     result = g.gts * b.baseline * ct.q2,
>     baseline = b.baseline * ct.q2
> from ct 
>   join gts as g
>     on  ct.ccp   = g.ccp
>     and ct.years = g.years 
>     and ct.quart = g.quart 
>   cross apply
>         ( select top (1) baseline
>           from baseline as b
>           where b.ccp = ct.ccp
>           order by years, quart
>         ) as b
>   ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CCP  | months | QUART | YEARS | GTS      | result        | baseline    
> :--- | -----: | ----: | ----: | :------- | :------------ | :-----------
> CCP1 |      1 |     1 |  2015 | 5.000000 | 25.000000     | 5.000000    
> CCP1 |      2 |     1 |  2015 | 6.000000 | 30.000000     | 5.000000    
> CCP1 |      3 |     1 |  2015 | 7.000000 | 35.000000     | 5.000000    
> CCP1 |      4 |     2 |  2015 | 4.000000 | 360.000000    | 90.000000   
> CCP1 |      5 |     2 |  2015 | 2.000000 | 180.000000    | 90.000000   
> CCP1 |      6 |     2 |  2015 | 2.000000 | 180.000000    | 90.000000   
> CCP1 |      7 |     3 |  2015 | 3.000000 | 2160.000000   | 720.000000  
> CCP1 |      8 |     3 |  2015 | 2.000000 | 1440.000000   | 720.000000  
> CCP1 |      9 |     3 |  2015 | 1.000000 | 720.000000    | 720.000000  
> CCP1 |     10 |     4 |  2015 | 2.000000 | 8640.000000   | 4320.000000 
> CCP1 |     11 |     4 |  2015 | 3.000000 | 12960.000000  | 4320.000000 
> CCP1 |     12 |     4 |  2015 | 4.000000 | 17280.000000  | 4320.000000 
> CCP1 |      1 |     1 |  2016 | 8.000000 | 311040.000000 | 38880.000000
> CCP1 |      2 |     1 |  2016 | 1.000000 | 38880.000000  | 38880.000000
> CCP1 |      3 |     1 |  2016 | 3.000000 | 116640.000000 | 38880.000000
> ```

Comment: As you have mentioned I faced rounding issues when using `LOG` and `EXP` functions. I have asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938890/rounding-issue-in-log-and-exp-functions Any ideas without CLR

Comment: Did you try my query above? But yes, log and exp may lead to slightly inaccurate results. You can avoid some of the troubles with rounding but it depends on how big the actual number are. I'll have a look at that question during the weekend. Are the actual numbers integers? How big can they be? How many are going to be multiplied? 10, 100, 1000 numbers? A million?

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if the question is how do the `over()` logic or perform a recursive cte in 2012 or just calculate in 2012 without recursive cte.

Looks like you were trying to create the `PRODUCT()` agreggation equivalent. But as I put in my comment

> The function 'Exp' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause.

So I did my version without recursive cte for my answer. I include one aditional year on the sample data with different baseline

- Calculate the total `gts` for each `Quart`
- Get the baseline from first `Quart`
- Calculate the base line for the other `Quart` doing the dummy `PRODUCT()` aggregated

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1bae/5)**

```
WITH gtsTotal as (
    SELECT [CCP], [Year], [QUART], SUM([GTS]) as sumGts
    FROM gts
    GROUP BY [CCP], [Year], [QUART]
), 
newBase as (
    SELECT g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR],  b.[BASELINE], 1 as sQuart, b.[BASELINE] as [TotalBase]
    FROM gtsTotal g
    INNER JOIN baseline b
       on g.[Year] = b.[YEARS]          
      and g.[CCP] = b.[CCP]
    WHERE g.[QUART] <= 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR],  b.[BASELINE], MAX(g.[QUART]) + 1 as sQuart, (Exp(Sum(Log(sumGts))) * b.[BASELINE]) as [TotalBase]
    FROM gtsTotal g
    INNER JOIN baseline b
       on g.[Year] = b.[YEARS]          
      and g.[CCP] = b.[CCP]        
    WHERE g.[QUART] <= 1
    GROUP BY g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR], b.[BASELINE]
            UNION ALL
    SELECT g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR],  b.[BASELINE], MAX(g.[QUART]) + 1 as sQuart, (Exp(Sum(Log(sumGts))) * b.[BASELINE]) as [TotalBase]
    FROM gtsTotal g
    INNER JOIN baseline b
       on g.[Year] = b.[YEARS]          
      and g.[CCP] = b.[CCP]        
    WHERE g.[QUART] <= 2
    GROUP BY g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR], b.[BASELINE]
            UNION ALL
    SELECT g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR],  b.[BASELINE], MAX(g.[QUART]) + 1 as sQuart, (Exp(Sum(Log(sumGts))) * b.[BASELINE]) as [TotalBase]
    FROM gtsTotal g
    INNER JOIN baseline b
       on g.[Year] = b.[YEARS]          
      and g.[CCP] = b.[CCP]        
    WHERE g.[QUART] <= 3
    GROUP BY g.[CCP],  g.[YEAR], b.[BASELINE]
)
SELECT g.CCP, g.months, g.QUART, g.Year, CEILING(g.GTS * n.TotalBase)
FROM newBase n
INNER JOIN gts g
   ON n.CCP = g.CCP
  AND n.[Year] = g.[Year]
  AND n.[sQuart] = g.[QUART]
order by g.[Year], n.sQuart
```

**Output**

```
|  CCP | months | QUART | Year | Result|
|------|--------|-------|------|-------|
| CCP1 |      1 |     1 | 2015 |    25 |
| CCP1 |      2 |     1 | 2015 |    30 |
| CCP1 |      3 |     1 | 2015 |    35 |
| CCP1 |      4 |     2 | 2015 |   360 |
| CCP1 |      5 |     2 | 2015 |   180 |
| CCP1 |      6 |     2 | 2015 |   180 |
| CCP1 |      7 |     3 | 2015 |  2160 |
| CCP1 |      8 |     3 | 2015 |  1440 |
| CCP1 |      9 |     3 | 2015 |   720 |
| CCP1 |     10 |     4 | 2015 |  8640 |
| CCP1 |     11 |     4 | 2015 | 12960 |
| CCP1 |     12 |     4 | 2015 | 17280 |
```

Comment: Problem is answer works for only one year. Sorry I have updated the sample data and expected result. Also it slower than my original answer

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is using stacked/cascaded CTEs:

```
;WITH CteFirstQtr AS(
    SELECT g.*, 
        result = b.BASELINE * g.GTS
    FROM gts g
    INNER JOIN BASELINE b
        ON b.CCP = g.CCP
        AND b.YEARS = g.YEARS
        AND b.QUART = g.QUART
),
CteSecondQtr AS(
    SELECT g.*,
        result = t.result * g.gts
    FROM gts g
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT SUM(result)
        FROM CteFirstQtr
        WHERE
            CCP = g.CCP
            AND Years = g.Years
            AND QUART = 1
    )t(result)
    WHERE g.QUART = 2
),
CteThirdQtr AS(
    SELECT g.*,
        result = t.result * g.gts
    FROM gts g
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT SUM(result)
        FROM CteSecondQtr
        WHERE
            CCP = g.CCP
            AND Years = g.Years
            AND QUART = 2
    )t(result)
    WHERE g.QUART = 3
),
CteFourthQtr AS(
    SELECT g.*,
        result = t.result * g.gts
    FROM gts g
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT SUM(result)
        FROM CteThirdQtr
        WHERE
            CCP = g.CCP
            AND Years = g.Years
            AND QUART = 3
    )t(result)
    WHERE g.QUART = 4
)
SELECT *  FROM CteFirstQtr UNION ALL
SELECT *  FROM CteSecondQtr UNION ALL
SELECT *  FROM CteThirdQtr UNION ALL
SELECT *  FROM CteFourthQtr
```

Comment: Sorry, Updated my sample data and expected result. Query is working for only one year. Can you please check

Answer (score 1):

No recursion, no loops.

```
DECLARE @BASELINE TABLE(CCP char(4),    BASELINE numeric(22,6),  YEARS  int ,QUART int)
DECLARE @gts TABLE (CCP char(4),months int,QUART int,YEARS int,GTS numeric(22,6))

insert into @baseline
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,5 AS BASELINE, 2015 AS YEARS,1 AS QUART 

insert into @gts (CCP,months,QUART,YEARS,GTS)
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,1 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  5 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,2 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  6 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,3 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  7 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,4 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  4 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,5 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  2 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,6 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  2 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,7 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  3 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,8 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  2 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,9 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  1 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,10 AS  months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 2  AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,11 AS months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  3 AS GTS  UNION
    SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,12 AS months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS,  4 AS GTS 



DECLARE @Summary TABLE (CCP char(4),[DATE] DATE,SumGTS numeric(22,6),AllPriorGTS numeric(22,6),[Multiplier] numeric(22,6))
INSERT INTO @Summary(CCP,[DATE],SumGTS)
    SELECT
            CCP,DATEADD(MONTH,(QUART-1)*3,DATEADD(YEAR,YEARS-2000,'01/01/2000')) [DATE]
        ,   SUM(GTS) [SumGTS]
    FROM @gts
    GROUP BY CCP,DATEADD(MONTH,(QUART-1)*3,DATEADD(YEAR,YEARS-2000,'01/01/2000'))

UPDATE s
SET AllPriorGTS=
    (
        SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(s1.SumGTS)))
        FROM @Summary s1
        WHERE s1.[Date]<s.[DATE]
    )
from @Summary s

UPDATE s
SET [Multiplier]=SumGTS*ISNULL(AllPriorGTS,1) * bl.BASELINE
from @Summary s
INNER JOIN @baseline bl ON bl.CCP = s.CCP


SELECT
    g.*,g.GTS*ISNULL(s.[Multiplier],bl.BASELINE) [RESULTS]
FROM @gts g
LEFT JOIN @Summary s ON DATEADD(MONTH,3,s.DATE)=DATEADD(MONTH,(g.QUART-1)*3,DATEADD(YEAR,g.YEARS-2000,'01/01/2000'))
LEFT JOIN @baseline bl ON bl.CCP = g.CCP
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a CTE.  I'd suggest possible working with the months and years in an actual date format.  I might become a bit easier to manage the transition of the Years 2015 vs 2016 becomes a simple DATEADD(MM,-1,dateCol) as opposed to figuring out when to subtract or add a year.  I haven't implemented in this solution, but could help if you needed it.  It could lead to a pretty effective indexing strategy to speed the query up if you have a large data set.  I believer it would also be possible to implement this with LAG as well.

```
create table #tmp_BASELINE (
CCP char(4),
BASELINE numeric(22,6),
YEARS int ,
QUART int)

create table #tmp_gts (
CCP char(4),
months int,
QUART int,
YEARS int,
GTS numeric(22,6)
)

insert into #tmp_BASELINE
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,10 AS BASELINE, 2015 AS YEARS,1 AS QUART 



insert into #tmp_gts
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,1 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 50 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,2 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 52 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,3 AS  months,1 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 57 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,4 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 59 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,5 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 61 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,6 AS  months,2 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 65 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,7 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 69 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,8 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 73 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,9 AS  months,3 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 78 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,10 AS  months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 84 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,11 AS months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 90 AS GTS  UNION
SELECT 'CCP1' AS CCP,12 AS months,4 AS QUART ,2015 AS YEARS, 95 AS GTS 

SELECT * FROM #tmp_BASELINE

SELECT CCP,
Months,
QUART,
YEARS,
GTS,
SUM(GTS) OVER (PARTITION BY QUART) as QTRGTS,
COALESCE((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(PGT.GTS) OVER (PARTITION BY QUART) FROM #tmp_gts as PGT WHERE GTS.YEARS = PGT.YEARS AND PGT.QUART = GTS.QUART-1),(SELECT TOP 1 BaseLine FROM #tmp_BASELINE)) as Modifier,
GTS * COALESCE((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(PGT.GTS) OVER (PARTITION BY QUART) FROM #tmp_gts as PGT WHERE GTS.YEARS = PGT.YEARS AND PGT.QUART = GTS.QUART-1),(SELECT TOP 1 BaseLine FROM #tmp_BASELINE)) as GTSxModifier
FROM #tmp_gts as GTS
```