# Multpilcation Aggregate in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create Multplication aggregate function from the below sql code.

```
declare @Floats as table (id int,value float)

insert into @Floats values (1,1)
insert into @Floats values (2,3)
insert into @Floats values (3,6)

SELECT *
FROM   @Floats a
       CROSS apply (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN MinVal = 0 THEN 0
                             WHEN Neg % 2 = 1 THEN -1 * Exp(ABSMult)
                             ELSE Exp(ABSMult)
                           END AS mul_value
                    FROM   (SELECT
                           Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF(Value, 0)))) AS ABSMult,
                           Sum(Sign(CASE
                                      WHEN Value < 0 THEN 1
                                      ELSE 0
                                    END))                  AS Neg,
                           Min(Abs(Value))                 AS MinVal
                            FROM   @Floats b
                            WHERE  a.id >= b.id) foo) cs
```

Result

```
id  value   mul_value
--  -----   ---------
1   1       1
2   3       3
3   6       18
```

Here is the idea for function. Since we we need table type to pass table as input to function am creating one below

User defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDT_TEST] AS TABLE( value float )
```

Function code

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Mul(@values dbo.[UDT_TEST] readonly)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @mul_value FLOAT

      SELECT @mul_value=CASE
               WHEN MinVal = 0 THEN 0
               WHEN Neg % 2 = 1 THEN -1 * Exp(ABSMult)
               ELSE Exp(ABSMult)
             END 
      FROM   (SELECT
             --log of +ve row values
             Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF(Value, 0)))) AS ABSMult,
             --count of -ve values. Even = +ve result.
             Sum(Sign(CASE
                        WHEN Value < 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END))                  AS Neg,
             --anything * zero = zero
             Min(Abs(Value))                 AS MinVal
              FROM   @values) foo

      RETURN @mul_value
  END
```

Using the function like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   @Floats a
       CROSS apply (SELECT dbo.udf_mul(value) ast
                            FROM   @Floats b
                            WHERE  a.id >= b.id)  cs
```

Here the problem is the input `dbo.udf_mul` expects parameter to be of `[dbo].[UDT_TEST]` type but value column is of `Float` type.

Error :

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 7 Operand type clash: float is
>   incompatible with UDT_TEST Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There is a way to create custom aggregates in SQL Server, but they have to be implemented in CLR. Even there, we'd struggle though since you're trying to implement an aggregate that depends on the order defined by a different column, and that's not going to work out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use scalar function for this type of operation. You end up with poor performance because query optimizer need to run it `row-by-row` without any optimalization. More info: [`SQL Server Functions: The Basics`](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/).

Second with float/decimal and `LOG/EXP` you will get approximation errors.

Third to pass data to function you can use `XML` like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Mul(@value xml)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @mul_value FLOAT;
      DECLARE @values AS TABLE ([value] float);

       INSERT INTO @values([value])
       SELECT [value] = t.c.value('(value)[1]', 'float')
      FROM @value.nodes('//row') AS t(c);


      SELECT @mul_value=CASE
               WHEN MinVal = 0 THEN 0
               WHEN Neg % 2 = 1 THEN -1 * Exp(ABSMult)
               ELSE Exp(ABSMult)
             END 
      FROM   (SELECT
             Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF(Value, 0)))) AS ABSMult,
             Sum(Sign(CASE
                        WHEN Value < 0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END))                  AS Neg,
             Min(Abs(Value))                 AS MinVal
              FROM   @values) foo

      RETURN @mul_value
  END
```

and calling it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Floats a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.udf_mul((SELECT [value]
                                 FROM Floats b
                                 WHERE a.id >= b.id
                                 FOR XML PATH, ROOT('root')))
             AS r) as cs(r);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fdb8/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ value  ║         r          ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1  ║     1  ║ 1                  ║
║  2  ║     3  ║ 3.0000000000000004 ║
║  3  ║     6  ║ 17.999999999999996 ║
║  4  ║     2  ║ 36                 ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════════════════╝
```